# how do I assign specific variables from Zapier into text fields in Docusign to auto populate the contract?

Tags: docusignapi, zapier, hellosign-api

I am passing a json file from salesmate into Zapier, and from Zapier I am passing those variables into docusign to auto populate a contract. some of the fileds like "company" and "email" are assigned correctly. however, I am unable to make custom assignments to specific fields. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions linking zapier to docusign or hellosign or any contract software?

```
{
    "title": "{{Task.title}}",
    "qty_of_units": "{{Task.textCustomField1}}",
    "term_of_rental": "{{Task.textCustomField2}}",
    "total_no_of_rental_payments": "{{Task.textCustomField3}}",
    "amount_of_each_payment": "{{Task.textCustomField4}}",
    "primaryContact": "{{Contact.name}}",
    "primaryCompany": "{{Company.name}}",
    "email": "{{Contact.email}}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Hazem from HelloSign API support and would happy to help with your ask.

When sending a signature request with HelloSign via Zapier, you will be using a template that holds custom fields assigned to the sender/signer. These fields can be pre-filled with data when sending the request. In this case you can use a JSON file to pass that data into the fields.

You can read more about this use-case below:

[Using-Editable-Merge-Fields-aka-Custom-Fields](https://faq.hellosign.com/hc/en-us/articles/216599897-Using-Editable-Merge-Fields-aka-Custom-Fields)

[Merge-fields-for-templates](https://faq.hellosign.com/hc/en-us/articles/216203807-Merge-fields-for-templates)

[Zapier-Sending-a-signature-request-from-a-template](https://faq.hellosign.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001654552-Zapier-Sending-a-signature-request-from-a-template)

I hope this help clear things up for you! Please let us know if you have any other questions or concerns.